# Removing a linked OpenID account

Tags: support, openid, linked-accounts, email, multiple-accounts

Apparently I was a dumbass and logged in once (persistent cookie) from a work-associated Gmail account (our Analytics account)... now some of my Stack Exchange accounts/posts are associated with this email.

It is a State of California position, so this is unacceptable and I need to get it fixed before it causes problems.

Is there any way (for me) to correct this issue and ensure all my stack accounts/posts/comments are tied only to my personal Gmail OpenID account?

Comment: Thought this was a dupe, but I can't find it.  I did find questions about linked SE accounts, but not multiple OpenIDs on a single account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your profile page → Edit Profile & Settings → My Logins and  remove the one you don't want.

Comment: I'll check this. Question though, will this delete any posts/comments made while logged in with these addresses or will they remain linked to the remaining login(s)?

Comment: You would merely be removing a login - not your associated account. It won't effect your posts.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer All posts under the account will remain unaffected by changing logins.

Comment: I remove it on the top right. But it still appears in Account section. How to remove it under account?

Comment: @hermes What "Account" section are you referring to?

Comment: When you click on user, it will direct to main page. Account is at the low left corner. Anyway I solve it by closing the linked account first and then logoff.